# How to find pattern in python list and update it with different value?

Tags: python

I am new in python and just started learning. I am trying to update a list which has the key-value pairs. now I want to update the original please see the format of the list

```
Orig_ndicator_list = [

    ('NAM', 'Rohit'),
    ('ADL', 'NONE'),
    ('AD1', 'BLR'),
    ('RPU', 'NONE'),
    ('AD2', 'PUNE'),
    ('AD3', 'DELHI'),
    ('CBR', 'NONE')

] 


updated_ind_list = [

    ('NAM', 'Kabir'),
    ('AD1', 'Mumbai'),
    ('AD2', 'Jaipur')

]
```

I have fine `NAM`, `AD1`, `AD2` in `Orig_ndicator_list` and want to update their values. the output should be like

```
[

    ('NAM', 'Kabir'),
    ('ADL', 'NONE'),
    ('AD1', 'Mumbai'),
    ('RPU', 'NONE'),
    ('AD2', 'Jaipur'),
    ('AD3', 'DELHI'),
    ('CBR', 'NONE')

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use comprehension:

```
d = dict(updated_ind_list)

result = [(i[0], d.get(i[0], i[1])) for i in Orig_ndicator_list]

result
#[('NAM', 'Kabir'),
# ('ADL', 'NONE'),
# ('AD1', 'Mumbai'),
# ('RPU', 'NONE'),
# ('AD2', 'Jaipur'),
# ('AD3', 'DELHI'),
# ('CBR', 'NONE')]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are are using a recent version of python where dictionary keys stay in order you can just pass both lists concatenated into the dictionary constructor.

```
d = dict(Orig_ndicator_list + updated_ind_list)
list(d.items())
```

**result**

```
[('NAM', 'Kabir'),
 ('ADL', 'NONE'),
 ('AD1', 'Mumbai'),
 ('RPU', 'NONE'),
 ('AD2', 'Jaipur'),
 ('AD3', 'DELHI'),
 ('CBR', 'NONE')]
```

This makes a new list rather than updating the original in place.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
Orig_ndicator_list = [('NAM', 'Rohit'), ('ADL', 'NONE'), ('AD1', 'BLR'), ('RPU', 'NONE'), ('AD2', 'PUNE'), ('AD3', 'DELHI'), ('CBR', 'NONE')] 
updated_ind_list = [('NAM', 'Kabir'), ('AD1', 'Mumbai'), ('AD2', 'Jaipur')]

Orig_ndicator_list = dict(Orig_ndicator_list)
for k,v in updated_ind_list:
    Orig_ndicator_list[k] = v

Orig_ndicator_list = list(Orig_ndicator_list.items())
print(Orig_ndicator_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[('AD2', 'Jaipur'), ('AD3', 'DELHI'), ('AD1', 'Mumbai'), ('NAM', 'Kabir'), ('CBR', 'NONE'), ('RPU', 'NONE'), ('ADL', 'NONE')]
```

---

To Maintain Order use `collections.OrderedDict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

Orig_ndicator_list = [('NAM', 'Rohit'), ('ADL', 'NONE'), ('AD1', 'BLR'), ('RPU', 'NONE'), ('AD2', 'PUNE'), ('AD3', 'DELHI'), ('CBR', 'NONE')] 
updated_ind_list = [('NAM', 'Kabir'), ('AD1', 'Mumbai'), ('AD2', 'Jaipur')]

Orig_ndicator_list = OrderedDict(Orig_ndicator_list)
for k,v in updated_ind_list:
    Orig_ndicator_list[k] = v

Orig_ndicator_list = list(Orig_ndicator_list.items())
print(Orig_ndicator_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[('NAM', 'Kabir'), ('ADL', 'NONE'), ('AD1', 'Mumbai'), ('RPU', 'NONE'), ('AD2', 'Jaipur'), ('AD3', 'DELHI'), ('CBR', 'NONE')]
```

Comment: It will append dict_items() in print. can I convert it in same list format?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand

Comment: I wanted to do list update, it got converted in dict. so again wanted it in list format. done this way:                                                                                      dict_list = []
for key, value in Orig_ndicator_list.items():
    temp = (key,value)
    dict_list.append(temp)

Comment: `Orig_ndicator_list = list(Orig_ndicator_list.items())` is a list.

Comment: Ohhh yes, Can you please answer why the order is changing of the list ? Can it be retained as original? I mean the order of indicators